# Creating a list from panda dataframe based on Index

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a datafarme with the following set up.

```
Product Clol1   Col2    Col3
pen       2     5       8
paper     6     7       4
shrpener  0     7       9
```

I want create list with the values for the index. = "paper".
Out put would be [6,7,4]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transpose your DataFrame and then select the desired column (ex row):

```
transposed_df = df.transpose()
result = transposed_df['paper']
```

Answer (score 1):

Select row by label with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and convert `Series` to list, I think transpose is not necessary (and also slowier):

```
out = df.loc['paper'].tolist()
```